# How to make the file list in a directory look cleaner in html/php?

Tags: php, html, indexing, localhost, webserver

I have a directory that houses pdf files housed in a mounted external drive on a localhost Raspberry Pi webserver. I'm able to get the vanilla "index of /pdfs" to show the files as hyperlinks, but it's not terribly aesthetically pleasing. I've read that there is a way to create a php script that essentially does the same thing with an opendir() function, but aside from the style.css, I'm unable to get the file list to come up. I've tried multiple different methods for the argument in opendir(), but can't seem to get the files to show up. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? The OS is Ubuntu Desktop so I'm doing this in Sublime and the terminal. I'm putting the php page inside the directory with the pdfs I want to display the links to but not sure if that is the place it is supposed to go. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you use Apache, there is fancy indexing module ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html ) that have a lot of options to do that.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried?

Comment: Stephen, tried this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/      I attempted to remove all the unecessaries...like the designations for different file types. The more I look at it, the more I am wondering if this is a website wide directory index as opposed to an index for a specific directory like "/media/ubuntu_server/library_pdfs/Biographies"

Comment: I'm able to get the css to show up from the directory I place it in, but the file links don't appear. Thinking it is the opendir() argument that is the problem.